# Failed to install dependency on Bluemix with a personal setup pypiserver

Tags: python, django, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to push a python Django application in Bluemix.

I use some global dependency, and a personal package which have some global dependency.

My application runs good, when I just add my personal package in my application folder.

e.g.in requirements.txt:

```
Mezzanine==4.1.0
cartridge
Django==1.9.7
-r ./my_personal_package/requirements.txt
```

in ./my_personal_package/requirements.txt:

```
pyOpenSSL==16.0.0
requests==2.9.1
psutil==4.3.0
```

But, if I package my personal package as a pypi package with pip tool. and put it in a personal pypi server that bluemix can access. My application will be failed to start. it failed on install a cffi package(Error message append in the end of this question)

my requirements.txt is as following:

```
-extra-index-url https://mypypiserver.mybluemix.net/repos/simple/
my-personal-package
Mezzanine==4.1.0
cartridge
Django==1.9.7
```

I compared the packages downloaded with method 1 and method 2, they are exactly the same. method 2 only failed on installing cffi:

```
2016-09-08T20:40:32.62-0500 [STG/0]      OUT          Running setup.py install for cffi: started
2016-09-08T20:40:33.42-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            Running setup.py install for cffi: finished with status 'error'
```

Error Messages:

```
016-09-08T20:40:33.43-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            Complete output from command /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-k3BUbl/cffi/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-C_rmOt-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
2016-09-08T20:40:33.43-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
2016-09-08T20:40:33.43-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
2016-09-08T20:40:33.43-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
2016-09-08T20:40:33.44-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
2016-09-08T20:40:33.44-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
2016-09-08T20:40:33.44-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
2016-09-08T20:40:33.44-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
2016-09-08T20:40:33.44-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
2016-09-08T20:40:33.44-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
2016-09-08T20:40:33.43-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
2016-09-08T20:40:33.43-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
2016-09-08T20:40:33.43-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
2016-09-08T20:40:33.44-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            No package 'libffi' found
2016-09-08T20:40:33.44-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
2016-09-08T20:40:33.44-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            No package 'libffi' found
2016-09-08T20:40:33.44-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
2016-09-08T20:40:33.44-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
2016-09-08T20:40:33.44-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            No package 'libffi' found
2016-09-08T20:40:33.44-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            running install
2016-09-08T20:40:33.44-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            running build
2016-09-08T20:40:33.44-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            running build_py
2016-09-08T20:40:33.44-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            creating build
2016-09-08T20:40:33.44-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
2016-09-08T20:40:33.44-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cffi
2016-09-08T20:40:33.44-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            copying cffi/cparser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cffi
2016-09-08T20:40:33.44-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            copying cffi/vengine_gen.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cffi
2016-09-08T20:40:33.44-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            copying cffi/commontypes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cffi
2016-09-08T20:40:33.44-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            copying cffi/lock.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cffi
2016-09-08T20:40:33.44-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            copying cffi/recompiler.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cffi
2016-09-08T20:40:33.44-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            copying cffi/backend_ctypes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cffi
2016-09-08T20:40:33.44-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            copying cffi/vengine_cpy.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cffi
2016-09-08T20:40:33.44-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            copying cffi/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cffi
2016-09-08T20:40:33.44-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            copying cffi/setuptools_ext.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cffi
2016-09-08T20:40:33.44-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            copying cffi/cffi_opcode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cffi
2016-09-08T20:40:33.44-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            copying cffi/model.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cffi
2016-09-08T20:40:33.44-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            copying cffi/ffiplatform.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cffi
2016-09-08T20:40:33.44-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            copying cffi/api.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cffi
2016-09-08T20:40:33.44-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            copying cffi/verifier.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cffi
2016-09-08T20:40:33.44-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            copying cffi/_cffi_include.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cffi
2016-09-08T20:40:33.44-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            copying cffi/parse_c_type.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cffi
2016-09-08T20:40:33.44-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            running build_ext
2016-09-08T20:40:33.44-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            building '_cffi_backend' extension
2016-09-08T20:40:33.44-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/c
2016-09-08T20:40:33.45-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DUSE__THREAD -I/usr/include/ffi -I/usr/include/libffi -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -c c/_cffi_backend.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/c/_cffi_backend.o
2016-09-08T20:40:33.45-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            c/_cffi_backend.c:15:17: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
2016-09-08T20:40:33.45-0500 [STG/0]      OUT             #include <ffi.h>
2016-09-08T20:40:33.45-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            compilation terminated.
2016-09-08T20:40:33.45-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
2016-09-08T20:40:33.45-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            ----------------------------------------
2016-09-08T20:40:33.44-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            copying cffi/_embedding.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cffi
2016-09-08T20:40:33.44-0500 [STG/0]      OUT            creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
2016-09-08T20:40:34.65-0500 [STG/0]      ERR Command "/app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-k3BUbl/cffi/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-C_rmOt-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-k3BUbl/cffi/
```

Comment: `2016-09-08T20:40:28.77-0500 [STG/0]      OUT        Collecting cffi>=1.4.1 (from cryptography>=1.3->pyOpenSSL==16.0.0->my-personal-package->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
2016-09-08T20:40:28.93-0500 [STG/0]      OUT          Downloading cffi-1.8.2.tar.gz (403kB)`

Comment: I'm not really sure how to answer your question, but just from looking through it, I wonder if the error comes at this point: "I package my personal package as a pypi package with pip tool. and put it in a personal pypi server that bluemix can access." Are you sure Bluemix is properly configured to access the server? Are you sure Bluemix can read the pypi package?

Answer (score 1):

The cffi installation failed due to "No package 'libffi' found". 'libffi' is notoriously messy to install and use. Since you are using a pypi server hosting dependence packages, the first place that I would like to check is whether the server is setup properly according to [cffi installation instructions](http://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html).